# How to hide particular column in Pivot Table using Apache POI (Java)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[while hiding column in pivot table. text above pivot table also getting removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAvrI.png)I want to hide one column in pivot table. If I remove that column then the functionality should not get effected. How can I achieve that functionality by removing or hiding that column in pivot table

```
public class Createxlsx {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
       createPivotTable();

    }


private static void createPivotTable() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("1e");
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("1econtent");
        XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 15);
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

         //  sheet.setTabColor(10);


       /* CTColor color = CTColor.Factory.newInstance(); 
        color.setIndexed(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex()); 
        sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetPr().setTabColor(color);*/
       // sheet1.setTabColor( new XSSFColor( Color.RED ) );
      //  sheet.setTabColor(1) 


        /*   CTColor color = CTColor.Factory.newInstance(); 
        color.setIndexed(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex()); 
        sheet1.getCTWorksheet().getSheetPr().setTabColor(color); */


     //   sheet1.setTabColor(0);



        //Set the tab color
    //  sheet.setTabColor(Color.getRed());

        //Save the Excel file
        //workbook.save(dataDir + "AsposeColoredTab_Out.xls");

        CellStyle fontStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        fontStyle.setFont(font);
        fontStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        fontStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
        fontStyle.setWrapText(true);



        CellStyle fontStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
        fontStyle1.setFont(font);
        fontStyle1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        fontStyle1.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
        fontStyle1.setWrapText(true);


        CellStyle fontStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
        fontStyle2.setFont(font);
        fontStyle2.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor();
        color.setARGBHex("fcd5b4");
        fontStyle2.setFillForegroundColor(color.getIndexed());
        fontStyle2.setWrapText(true);

        CellStyle fontStyle3 = wb.createCellStyle();
        fontStyle3.setFont(font);
        fontStyle3.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        XSSFColor color1 = new XSSFColor();
        color1.setARGBHex("fcd5b4");
        fontStyle3.setFillForegroundColor(color1.getIndexed());
        fontStyle3.setWrapText(true);


        sheet1.setDisplayGridlines(false);
        sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4,7,0,5));
        sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,5));
        sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,1,5));
        sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2,2,1,5));
        sheet1.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(3,3,0,5));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, 25*256);
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, 45*256);

        Row row1 = sheet1.createRow(0);
        Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell11.setCellStyle(fontStyle);
        cell11.setCellValue("XXX");



        Row row2 = sheet1.createRow(1);
       // row2.setRowStyle(fontStyle);
        //row2.setRowStyle(fontStyle2);
        Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
        //CellStyle alignCellStyle = cell21.getCellStyle();
        CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        //alignCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        cell21.setCellValue("Preparued for:");
        cell21.setCellStyle(fontStyle2);
        Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
        cell22.setCellValue("Rerrrrts Tests");
        cell22.setCellStyle(fontStyle2);


        Row row3 = sheet1.createRow(2);
       // row3.setRowStyle(fontStyle2);
        Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
        CellStyle alignCellStyle1 = cell31.getCellStyle();
        alignCellStyle1.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        cell31.setCellValue("Time Period:");
        cell31.setCellStyle(fontStyle2);
        Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
        DataFormat poiFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
        CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        String excelFormatPattern = DateFormatConverter.convert(Locale.US, "mm/dd/yyyy");
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(poiFormat.getFormat(excelFormatPattern));
        cell32.setCellValue(new Date());
        cell32.setCellStyle(fontStyle2);


        Row row4 = sheet1.createRow(3);
        Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
        cell41.setCellValue("Table 1e: Confs Created ");
        //row4.setRowStyle(fontStyle1);
        cell41.setCellStyle(fontStyle1);

        Row row5 = sheet1.createRow(4);
        //row5.setRowStyle(fontStyle2);
        Cell cell51 = row5.createCell(0);
        cell51.setCellValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        cell51.setCellStyle(fontStyle3);


        setCellData(sheet,wb);
        wb.getSheet("1econtent").setSelected(false);
        wb.setSheetVisibility(wb.getSheetIndex("1econtent"),SheetVisibility.VISIBLE);

        AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:D5", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
        CellReference position = new CellReference(10,0);

         XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet1.createPivotTable(source, position,wb.getSheet("1econtent"));

         pivotTable.addReportFilter(2);
         pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1,"% of value");

         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setShowDataAs(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STShowDataAs.PERCENT_OF_COL);
         DataFormat dataformat = wb.createDataFormat();
         short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.00%");
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(1).setNumFmtId(numFmtId); 

         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).setAutoShow(false);
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(0).unsetT();
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(0).setX((long)0);
         pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(0).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("Jane");
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPageFields().getPageFieldArray(0).setItem(0);


         sheet1.getRow(10);
         pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotTableStyleInfo().setName("PivotStyleMedium10");




        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pivottablesa.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
}

public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet,XSSFWorkbook wb){


        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell11.setCellValue("Names");
        Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
        cell12.setCellValue("Confts");
        Cell cell13 = row1.createCell(2);
        cell13.setCellValue("ConftsAS");
        Cell cell14 = row1.createCell(3);
        cell14.setCellValue("Human");


        Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
        cell21.setCellValue("Jane");
        Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
        cell22.setCellValue(10);
        Cell cell23 = row2.createCell(2);
        cell23.setCellValue(100);
        Cell cell24 = row2.createCell(3);
        cell24.setCellValue("Yes");

        Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
        Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
        cell31.setCellValue("Tarzan");
        Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
        cell32.setCellValue(5);
        Cell cell33 = row3.createCell(2);
        cell33.setCellValue(100);
        Cell cell34 = row3.createCell(3);
        cell34.setCellValue("Yes");

        Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
        Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
        cell41.setCellValue("Terk");
        Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
        cell42.setCellValue(10);
        Cell cell43 = row4.createCell(2);
        cell43.setCellValue(90);
        Cell cell44 = row4.createCell(3);
        cell44.setCellValue("No");
        cell44.getCellStyle().setHidden(false);

        Row row5 = sheet.createRow(4);
        Cell cell211 = row5.createCell(0);
        cell211.setCellValue("Jane");
        Cell cell221 = row5.createCell(1);
        cell221.setCellValue(10);
        Cell cell231 = row5.createCell(2);
        cell231.setCellValue(60);
        Cell cell241 = row5.createCell(3);
        cell241.setCellValue("No");
        cell241.getCellStyle().setHidden(false);

    }
}
```

I want to hide one column in pivot table So [as shown in this Image I want to hide first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIjAb.png) how can I hide.

Comment: Particular field or row or column ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide all extra excel columns with Apache-POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326333/hide-all-extra-excel-columns-with-apache-poi)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Comment: Can anyone now help me out for above problem

Comment: Not solved still any other solution?

Comment: No solution for the above Issue?